# How to type into this text field with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

This is a snippet of my test:

```
# enter credit card number
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.switch_to.frame("billingFormFrame") 

cc = driver.find_element_by_id("creditCardNumber")
cc.click()
cc.send_keys("4111111111111111")

# enter expiration
selectmonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expirationMonth"))
selectmonth.select_by_value("10")
```

the test errors out at the #expiration block, but my question is why does the credit card field not populate with 4111111111111?  I don't receive an error related to the creditCardNumber field, yet no value is entered.  What am I doing wrong there?

To be clear, my question is not why am I getting an error, but why is no credit card number value showing?

And if anyone cares to follow along:

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-presto-ultra-flyknit-shoe/pid-10997057/pgid-11044479

- add shoe to cart
- click guest checkout
- the payment information page is where I'm having issues.

Comment: I can't get to payment page- a lot of information required :) To make it clear: you try to send text to input field, but it still empty? That is the problem?

Comment: correct, this is the problem

Comment: could you update your question with `HTML` code for target input field?

Comment: Did you try changing the function `switch_to_frame` and pass a list of frame id instead of a string ? I guess you should try it once. In your case, do, `driver.switch_to.frame(["billingFormFrame"])`